# ChatGPT clients on Android, and storing and sharing conversations

Tags: android, chat, search

I have started to use ChatGPT to answer my questions, without getting distracted (by search results, and advertisements).

This is relatively effective on Android applications such as the new version of the Microsoft Bing app.

There are also other apps, but I cannot stand the ads.

The latest version of ChatGPT available seems to be ChatGPT 4.

I wouldn't mind paying for a ChatGPT app.

However, I would like it to remember my question she answer conversations and store them in the cloud, for separate access.

Currently, these apps don't seem to do this.

Bing, for instance, erases everything, and when you try to export something, for instance, to Google Keep, it only exports the latest search result, rather than the whole conversation.

Is it possible to achieve the result I want.

Is anyone willing to implement the behavior I'm asking for, and, programming wise, what would it take (the difficult part is the ChatGPT part, or, are there open source libraries that implement ChatGPT available for Android)?

Is anyone willing to implement every I'm looking for?

Where can I find a good ChatGPT client, on Android?